# how to update a Python package (Pandas) manually?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, pycharm, anaconda

Hi I have both Pycharm and Anaconda installed on my computer and I would like to upgrade the package Pandas to the latest version (i have the 0.14 version)

Unfortunately my computer has strong firewall restrictions and I am not able to use the internet to update it. I can download the source files though.

Is there a way to install the package manually? I use win 7 64 by the way

Many thanks!!!

Comment: What is so confusing? Download it from PyPi and run the setup script.

Comment: Just download the archive from `pypi` and use `pip install </path/to/archive.zip>`

Comment: im trying but I get a lot of strange messages in the anaconda console like warnings too many arguments for format etc .. and keep repeating the same stuff over and over

Comment: also can use conda:  ```conda install path/filename``` where path/filename is the exact path and filename of what you downloaded.  Also try the conda mailing list:  https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!forum/anaconda

Comment: @JohnE i also tried and i get could not connect to htt://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64 (why it need to connect to the internet at all??) and error: no packages found in current win-64 channels matching c:\users\etc\pandas-0.16.0.zip... :-(

Comment: I also got that error message but it still installed the downloaded program for me.  You can just ignore that message if you do the rest of it correctly.  I think there may be a flag that avoids that error message, but again, shouldn't really matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using conda, use the `--offline` flag when installing the conda package that you downloaded, like `conda install --offline pandas-0.15.2-np19py27.tar.bz2`.